# Fibonacci numbers - dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, fibonacci

I want to write Fibonacci number program, using dynamic array in function. If I want to initialize array in the function, where I must delete this array? Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* fibo(int);

int main()
{
    int *fibonacci, n;
    cout << "Enter how many fibonacci numbers you want to print: ";
    cin >> n;
    fibonacci = fibo(n);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cout << fibonacci[i] << " ";

    //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        //delete w_fibo[i];
    //delete[] w_fibo;

    return 0;
}

int* fibo(int n)
{
    int* w_fibo = new int[n];
    if (n >= 0)
        w_fibo[0] = 1;
    if (n >= 1)
        w_fibo[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        w_fibo[i + 1] = w_fibo[i] + w_fibo[i - 1];

    return w_fibo;
}
```

Comment: Use the vector class, is easier.

Comment: You can do like this `delete[] fibonacci;` at the end of your main function before return 0;

Comment: @VikasVerma This cause error http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2r5zukz&s=8

Comment: @Kulis  Its working on g++

Comment: @Kulis  and if you are using this statement 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete fabonacci[i];
in your program then dont use it because you are not created array of pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to initialize the array! a better dynamic Fibonacci presentation could be like this:

```
int fib2 (int n) {
int i = 1, j = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) { // The loop begins to work real after one loop (k == 1). Sounds interesting!
    j += i;                   // Adds the produced number to the last member of the sequence and makes a new sentence.
    i = j - i;                // Produces the number that should be added to the sequence.
    }
return j;
}
```

and you can get the n-th fib number using this method. It's O(log(n)) so it's so efficient.`

```
int fib3 (int n) {

int i = 1, j = 0, k = 0, h = 1, t=0;     
while (n > 0) {

    if (n % 2) {                                        //  |
        t = j * h;                                      //  |
        j = i * h + j * k + t;
        i = i * k + t;
    }
    t = h * h;
    h = 2 * k * h + t;
    k = k * k + t;
    n /= 2;
    }
   return j;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate a `std::vector<int>` inside `fibo()` and reserve enough memory, and then return it by value, the memory allocation is taken care for you by the compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<int> fibo(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> w_fibo;
    w_fibo.reserve(n);

    if (n >= 0)
        w_fibo[0] = 1;
    if (n >= 1)
        w_fibo[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        w_fibo[i + 1] = w_fibo[i] + w_fibo[i - 1];

    return w_fibo;
}

int main()
{    
    int n = 10;
    std::vector<int> fibonacci = fibo(n);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cout << fibonacci[i] << " ";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/162a3ef4cfed07b2).

**NOTE**: This is guaranteed to avoid needlessly copying in C++11 (move semantics) and is likely to do so in C++98 (copy-elision using the return-value-optimization).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but just in case someone happens to pass by this might be helpful.

If you need a efficient method to get the nth Fibonacci number, we have a O(1) time complexity procedure.

It is based on [Binet's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268056/nth-term-in-the-fibonacci-series), which I think our friends over at math.se will be better at proving, so feel free to follow that link.

The formula itself is, given a=1.618 and b=-0.618 (these are approximate values)

the n-th term is (a^n - b^n)/2.236. A good way to round that off(since we are using approximate values) would be adding 0.5 and taking the floor function.

```
math.floor(((math.pow(1.618,n)-math.pow(-0.618,n))/2.236 + 0.5)
```